# regex not working as expected for full name

Tags: java, regex

I have a textbox where I am taking input as full name.

When user enter input as `My Name`, I don't get any error. However when user enter input as `My Name Is`, I get error.

Regex I have is

```
([a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\\s[a-zA-Z]+)
```

What actually want is, text should have

```
only (a-z OR A-Z) AND white space...
```

Demo Inputs are

1. My Name is XYZ PQR STU
2. My Name is XYZ
3. XYZ PQR STU

How this can be done using regex?

### Update 1

I am using

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z\\s]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("DummyName");
    boolean matchFound = m.matches();
```

still I am getting `matchFound` as `FALSE`

Comment: I think you should make your question a bit more clear, now you are saying that only white space is acceptable for a name? Maybe show some acceptable input?

Comment: If you use Eclipse, you could try the QuickREx plugin to do some realtime testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s` is for whitespace.  If you want to allow whitespace in a character class as well as upper and lowercase letters, you would use `[a-zA-Z\s]`.

Comment: in your update, your pattern is only going to match 1 character.  Try matching `([a-zA-Z\s]+)` if you want the full name in one group. Or `([a-zA-Z\s]+?)+` if you want multiple groups.

Comment: I have updated my question.. see possible inputs... what should I use?

Comment: Well that's really up to you, but if I'm gleaning your intentions correctly, I would guess you want `([a-zA-Z\s]+)`.  That will accept any nonempty set of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and whitespace.

Comment: You don't need the '?' behind '+' I think.

Comment: @owlstead Yeah... you're totally right.  I just threw the more complicated one down in a hurry.  I think `[a-zA-Z\s]+` is what he really wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one `^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*$`. You can tweak it a bit for your tastes. The `?:` is to make sure that the group does not capture - which is not needed if you are just testing the full string. `^` and `$` will match the start and the end of the input text - not directly required for `matches()` but it's a good safeguard.